# I want to get all urls of website by php script, is this possible or not?

Tags: php

I want to get all urls of website by php script, is this possible or not ?

Make sure it is not for one page only.

If i enter one domain name then i want all urls on that website even its inner pages also.

Comment: PHP XML Sitemap - https://www.plop.at/en/php.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try a sitemap generator like: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/